# What is a 甘えるような態度?

Tags: meaning

I'm not asking for a translation, but rather what kind of gestures/actions/behavior does it refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are acting overfamiliar, overintimate, etc. in order to be taken under someone's wing or to cadge for things, a Japanese-speaker might call it a 「[甘]{あま}えるような[態度]{たいど}」.